# using phone gap in website/ WebApplication

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to use the Phone Gap API in a website?

I want to read GPS information from phones. Is this possible in a website or can I only do it in a native application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it is not possible to use the PhoneGap API within the mobile browser as the API is available for the native application only.

If you simply need to get the GPS information within the mobile browser, you can have a look at the following related questions:

- [Is it possible to detect a mobile browser's GPS location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762141/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-mobile-browsers-gps-location)
- [Get position data from mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97865/get-position-data-from-mobile-browser)